# Submitting a Bug on Launchpad when there are Missing Debug Packages?

Tags: launchpad, apport

I submitted a bug report to Launchpad using Apport. Shortly after, I received the following email:

> Thank you for your report!
>
> However, processing it in order to get sufficient information for the
>   developers failed (it does not generate a useful symbolic stack trace). This
>   might be caused by some outdated packages which were installed on your system
>   at the time of the report:
>
> outdated -dbg package for libdrm-radeon1: package version 2.4.91-2~16.04.1 -dbg version 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1
>   no debug symbol package found for libboost-filesystem1.58.0
>   outdated -dbg package for libdrm-nouveau2: package version 2.4.91-2~16.04.1 -dbg version 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1
>   no debug symbol package found for libcairo-gobject2
>   no debug symbol package found for libboost-system1.58.0
>   outdated -dbg package for libdrm2: package version 2.4.91-2~16.04.1 -dbg version 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1
>   outdated -dbg package for libwayland-cursor0: package version None -dbg version 1.9.0-1
>   outdated -dbg package for libdrm-amdgpu1: package version 2.4.91-2~16.04.1 -dbg version 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1
>   no debug symbol package found for libogg0
>   no debug symbol package found for libatk1.0-0
>   outdated -dbg package for libwayland-client0: package version None -dbg version 1.9.0-1
>
> Please upgrade your system to the latest package versions. If you still
>   encounter the crash, please file a new report.

The problem is that I have checked in Synaptic, and all of the packages referred to either don't exist, or the debug package is out-of date (and there isn't a new one that matches the main package). Can someone advise as to how I can submit this bug report, please?

I have read the page about ApportRetracingService on the Community Help Wiki. It accurately describes the situation I am in, but offers no help on how to remedy it!

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64
 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Output of `apt-cache policy libwayland-client0 libdrm-radeon1`:

```
libwayland-client0:
  Installed: 1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3
  Candidate: 1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.9.0-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libdrm-radeon1:
  Installed: 2.4.91-2~16.04.1
  Candidate: 2.4.91-2~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.91-2~16.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.67-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I'm on 16.04 (64-bit), and I made sure to do a software update before generating the crash report.

Comment: Just making sure, but have you run `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` recently?  It might just be out of date repository information.  If you try submitting the report *now* it might work, because it was complaining about you having the old non-`xenial-{security,updates}` packages.  Which it seems are no longer installed and the newer ones are.  (You should be able to resubmit the bug report *if* the bug still happens)

Comment: I ran both of those commands (as sudo) and installed all upgrades proposed (only 3). I then tried submitting the bug report again, but got the same message (the bug still happens). Could it be to do with the fact that, in order to get the bug to open a Launchpad bug report, I have had to comment out the following line in `/etc/apport/crashdb.conf`: `'problem_types': ['Bug', 'Package']`?